# two sided page layout using CSS

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I wondering how the Newspaper page can be set in XHTML using CSS.

How to use `CSS` so that the content of `XHTML` will be divided in two columns just like newspaper layout?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Take a look at [CSS Columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) and this [Guide to Responsive-Friendly CSS Columns](http://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/)

Comment: What you have tried so far?Provide the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could so this with [CSS Columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns).  They [don't have great support in anything but the newest browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) but you could use a [JS Polyfill](https://github.com/BetleyWhitehorne/CSS3MultiColumn) for older browsers.

CSS-Tricks.com has a great [Guide to Responsive-Friendly CSS Columns](http://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/) but here's the TL;DR version as a proof of concept:

```css
article {
  -webkit-columns: 3 200px;
  -moz-columns: 3 200px;
  columns: 3 200px;
}
article p {
  margin-bottom:1.5em;
}
```

```html
<article>
<p>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis.</p>
<p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
<p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
<p>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Donec sed odio dui. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>  
</article>
```

Comment: That's what I'm loking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using #col1{ float:left; } and #col2 {float:left; margin-left:25px; } will give you this effect as well and will work in IE9 and earlier.